# How does a bitwise AND (or TEST) with 16 test the 5th bit?

Tags: assembly, x86, bitwise-operators, x86-16

In my College's documentation on 8086 Assembly is the following example:

```
TEST AL, 16      ; tests the 5th bit's state
```

Is this at all correct given what [the TEST instruction does](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/TEST.html)?   It sets flags based on `AL & 16`.  How does that test the 5th bit?

NOTE: there's no previously mentioned value to AL, just exactly what's shown here, so I assume this has to work in the general case.

Comment: Actually I just realized I may have been too harsh here.  You didn't say *what* your understanding of the TEST instruction was, so I assumed that was what the question was really about.  If the main point of your question was how and-with-`0x10` tests the 5th bit, then please [edit] to clarify that.  I'll probably remove my downvote.  (I'm not trying to be a jerk, I'm just trying to discourage asking new questions without searching first, because duplicates dilute the search results for future readers.)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to keep this forum clean and thank you for pointing out the fault in this post that could easily lead to seeing it as a lazy duplicate. If any other edits are needed, please do say it. Thank you!

Comment: Adding a note at the end is much less useful than changing the original text so it's not unclear in the first place.  I did it for you to show you what I meant, hope that makes it clear and helps you write better questions in the future. :)  The hard part of asking questions is quickly making it clear what you know and what you need an explanation for, especially when it's a beginner question.

Comment: I've had my share of "trouble" on this forum for not being able to quickly get to the point, so i must say i really appreciate your help. Thank you, once again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`16` in decimal is `10000` in binary. Notice the fifth bit from the right is set, and that it is the only one.

`TEST` is bitwise AND. The result of a bitwise AND operation is a value that has `1`'s wherever there was a `1` in both original values. For example:

```
a       = 1010 1110
b       = 0110 1011
a AND b = 0010 1010
```

Supposing `a` was `AL` and `b` was `16`:

```
AL        = xxxx xxxx
16        = 0001 0000
AL AND 16 = 000y 0000
```

The result can be either `0`, if the fifth bit of AL is `0`, or it can be `16`, if the fifth bit of `AL` is `1`. If the instruction using the result of the `TEST` instruction was, for example, a conditional jump, like JNZ, then it does in fact 'test' if the fifth bit of `AL` is set and acts according to the result.

To be more precise, the result is used indirectly – only various flags are set. In this case, the `ZF` flag is relevant. Depending on the result of the bitwise AND operation, `ZF` is either set to `0` if the result was `0` or it is set to `1` if the result was not `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. This was helpful.

Comment: Just to point out `TEST` is non-destructive as opposed to `AND`